# Apache - Files directive does not work

Tags: httpd

HI guys.

when i configure Files in this way:

```
<Files ~ "\.png$">
    deny from all
</Files>
```

it works. but when defining in this way it doesn't work:

```
<Files /var/www/test/file.png>
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Directives are not inside `Directory` directive.
Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the apache manual it says that Files directive should be coupled with the Directory directive. Therefore to achieve the functionality you are looking for use

```
<Directory /var/www/test>
 <Files ~ "file\.png">
   deny from all 
 <Files>
</Directory>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#files

Comment: Careful, as `<Directory>` directives are not allowed in *.htaccess* files.

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but this answer did not actually answer the question.  a <Files> directive does not have to be inside a directory directive.  If it is, then it's limited by the enclosing <Directory> directive, but this answer did not explain why things didn't work as expected, so I'm not sure why this was the accepted answer.